# How do I detect who runs my application?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have built some applications that runs from a shared folder within our company network. I have simply placed the .exe-file there. This work fine until I need to replace the file when upgraded. If someone runs said application, the file is locked.

Can I somehowe detect which user currently runs my application? Or even better, can I shut it down?

Comment: Try using sockets and check whether the person is available or not.

Comment: you can use a third party tool such as [psfile](http://ss64.com/nt/psfile.html)

Comment: Thank you Rex. I forgot to tell that I am very novice when it comes to technical terms in Windows. What is "sockets"? :)

Comment: If the app is updated often, post the current copy on the network, write a "loader" that checks to see if that copy is newer, then copy it to the local drive and run it.  That way you can update the "master" any time you want (except when someone is starting the app and it is being copied).  Who is running it is irrelevant unless the intent is to call them and tell them to exit the app.  That would only reveal the users one at a time anyway

Comment: If you view the file share via Window's Computer Management, you can see who has the file open.

Comment: Plutonix: good idea. I don´t update that often. I was aiming for what you suggested: ask them to exit the application.

Comment: If you use the Publish feature in Visual Studio, it will give you a setup that you can have your users install on their machines.  There's an option to make it automatically check for an update every time they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring up the Project Properties and go to the Publish tab.

Set the Publishing Folder to the UNC path to where you want your users to get the program from.

Play around with the Updates and Options.  There's an option to make it check for updates every time the user runs the program.

Then run the Publish Wizard.

Now your users can go to that folder and run the setup.exe there.  The program will be installed on their local machines so you can update it later.

Comment: I used to do this way, but I had some issues where wrong version of my application opened. But maybe I give it another try. Thanks!